# Using mixed effects modelling to estimate and compare variability

Tags: variance, mixed-model

Say I observe two groups of 10 people, measuring some quantity 100 times in each person. There will presumably be some variability across these 100 measures in each person. Can I use mixed effects analysis to assess whether this within-person variability is, on average, different between the two groups? For example, using traditional statistics, I could compute the standard deviation (SD) within each person then submit these SDs to an anova comparing the groups, but I wonder if this two-stage process can be replaced by a single mixed effects model, consequently obtaining the various advantages of mixed effects modelling (shrinkage, accounting for different numbers of observations per person, etc) as well.

To be clear, here is R code depicting the scenario described above and the SD/anova-based approach:

```
set.seed(1)

group_A_base_sd = 1
group_B_base_sd = 2
within_group_sd_of_sds = .1

n_per_group = 10
obs_per_id = 100

temp = data.frame(
    id = 1:(n_per_group*2)
    , group = rep(c('A','B'))
)

#generate example data
library(plyr) #to avoid loops (for coding convenience only)
obs_data = ddply(
    .data = temp
    , .variables = .(id,group)
    , .fun = function(x){
         #generate a unique sd for this individual
         # based on their group's sd plus some
         # within-group variability
         id_sd = ifelse(
              x$group=='A'
              , rnorm(
                   1
                   , group_A_base_sd
                   , within_group_sd_of_sds
              )
              , rnorm(
                   1
                   , group_B_base_sd
                   , within_group_sd_of_sds
              )
         )
         #generate data points with the above generated
         # variability
         to_return = data.frame(
              obs_num = 1:obs_per_id
              , measurement = rnorm(obs_per_id,0,id_sd)
         )
         return(to_return)
    }
)

#first step of an anova-based approach:
# compute SDs within each Ss
obs_sds = ddply(
    .data = obs_data
    , .variables = .(id,group)
    , .fun = function(x){
         to_return = data.frame(
              obs_sd = sd(x$measurement)
         )
    }
)

#second step of an anova-based approach:
# compute the anova on the SDs
summary(
    aov(
         formula = obs_sd~group
         , data = obs_sds
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can structure the model along the following lines. Let,

$j = 1, 2$ be the two groups and

$i$ index the individuals in the two groups.

Then your model is:

$y_{ij} \sim N(\mu_j,\sigma_j^2)$  $\forall \ i, j$

$\sigma_j^2 \sim IG(v,1)$  $\forall \ j$

(Note: $IG(.)$ is the inverse gamma distribution.)

**Priors**

$\mu_j \sim N(\bar{\mu},\sigma_{\mu}^2)$

$v \sim IG(\bar{v},1)$ is the prior for $v$.

The above structure will let you shrink the error variances ($\sigma_j^2$) appropriately. You can then evaluate whether the within group variability is different by looking at the credible intervals associated with the group variabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate SD for each person and its standard error (for example using bootstrap). Then you can use **rmeta** package to do analysis. I think you should use some transformation of SD for example log (or maybe better log of variance).